# use-package and js2-mode: setting fill-column

Tags: use-package, js2-mode

I'm using `use-package` and I want my `fill-column` to be set to `100` for files edited with `js2-mode`.

I tried to do so in the `:config` part, like:

```
(use-package js2-mode
  :config
  (setq fill-column 100))
```

(among other configuration) but it didn't work, `fill-column` was still `70` after loading a JS file (which activated `js2-mode`).

The way I made it work was by setting `fill-column` inside a hook like:

```
(use-package js2-mode
  :preface
  (defun me/js2-hook ()
    (setq fill-column 100))
  :config
  (add-hook 'js2-mode-hook #'me/js2-hook))
```

So, my question is, what was wrong with setting `fill-column` straight into `:config`?  Why is the hook required?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fill-column` immediately becomes buffer-local when set. So, when your config is evaluated, that buffer's `fill-column` is set... but then nothing else happens. If you set it with a hook, then `fill-column` will be set any time that hook is fired -- that is, every time a new buffer is created in `js2-mode`, and then `fill-column` will be set for that buffer.

You can, if you want, change the global *default* value of `fill-column` from 70 (which is silly) to another number, outside of `use-package`, like so:

```
(setq-default fill-column 79)
```